# How to accept a list of integers as input and create an object for each item in the list in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have to pass a request body as shown below.

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "skill": [
      {
          "id":1
      },
      {
          "id":2
      }, 
      {
          "id":3
      }
  ]
}
```

Models looks like this:

```
class UserSkill(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  skill = models.ForeignKey(Skills, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  class Meta:
      db_table = "user_skill"
```

Serializer looks like :

```
class UserSkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
      model = UserSkill
      fields = ['user', 'skill']
```

Viewset is done like:

```
class UserSkillViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = UserSkill.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserSkillSerializer
```

I have to pass the above mentioned request body to this api and for each element in "skill", I have to create an object for the model "UserSkill".

Some one please help me with the changes I have to make to get this api working.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserSkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
      model = UserSkill
      fields = ['user', 'skill']

  def create(self, validated_data):
    user_id = validated_data.get('user_id')
    skill_ids = validated_data.get('skill')
    skill = [item.get("id") for item in skill_ids]
    super().create({"user": user_id, "skill": skill})
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

change your `skill` field in `UserSkill` model to ManyToManyField. like:

```
class UserSkill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skills)

    class Meta:
          db_table = "user_skill"
```

and you need to pass a request body like this.

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "skill": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

without any change in serializer and view classes your requirements applicated.

if you want to use ForeignKey you need to some implementation in your view and you must overwrite `create` function in `ModelViewSet`.

Comment: @aryan-vr If you want to request body used without any change must be need to use nested serializer relation of django rest framework, for this implement serializer for Skiils and used that on UserSkillSerializer as a field.